# Recovering images after formatted HDD & new OS install

Tags: windows, hard-drive, file-recovery

Not sure if this is correct place to ask my question but I thought I could get best answers here. So as the topic says, I've problem with recovering some images from a formatted hard drive. HDD was formatted using recovery console in Windows 7 boot disk and utily I used was [Diskpart](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300415). Commands I entered were:

```
diskpart
list disk
Select disk 0
clean
convert mbr
create partition primary
select partition 1
format fs=ntfs quick
```

After this I reinstalled Windows 7. I know it is possible to retrieve some data from memory if you haven't written new data to disk. I also know that it is highly recommend to backup everything before format, but mistakes happen even to best of us. I already tried to retrieve photos with a freeware program called [iCare Format Recovery v5.0](http://www.formatted-recovery.com/) with no great success, it did found many files and even some working photos, but most of those were so small (like thumbnails) that they got no use. Most of files it found, were corrupted and showed up like the cryptographic text when I tried to preview them.

HDD is 465GB in size and with Win 7 and few programs installed on it only takes 26GB of data, so there is still 439GB's of free space left. I thought there might be small chance that the photos are not overwritten? Is there anything I can do or am I doomed? Maybe you can recommend some programs I could give a try?

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [**TestDisk**](http://cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) with great success, but I dont know how effective it will be with the great "trauma" your drive has been through.

Answer (score 0):

[**OnTrack Easy Recovery Pro**](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&safe=off&biw=1680&bih=924&sclient=psy-ab&q=easy+recovery+pro&oq=easy+recovery+pro&gs_l=hp.3..0i20j0j0i10j0.310.2103.0.3372.17.13.0.1.1.3.789.3407.0j6j4j5-1j1.12.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.5kGy7KbOMeY&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.eWU&fp=5953c7bed57240e&bpcl=40096503) has been helpful for me in these situations. It's made by OnTrack, the same people whom you'd pay thousands to physically extract the platters of your inoperable drive and recover data off it. I've linked to some product reviews for it, it can recover files and folders even from a formatted disk.

Comment: It should be clearly noted that this is not free software, in fact hefty price of $149 per year.

Comment: Very true, this is commercial software; didn't realize they'd started charging as a subscription, last time I used it you only paid a one-time fee for a Pro license.